# How should I find the rows with a duplicate field in a big table?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, bigtable

I have a table with 1.5M+ rows for recording downloads from a website which has email address of the one who has downloaded something. I want to find those who have downloaded more than 100 times. This is what I have tested but the `query-time` is more than 11 seconds when I test it on the server! Do you know any faster way?

```
SELECT  `email`
FROM  `table_of_downloads` 
GROUP BY  `email` 
HAVING COUNT( * ) >100
```

Here is the EXPLAIN results as requested:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  table_of_downloads  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1656546 Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others to know, I just changed the type from `tinytext` to `varchar(128)` and the query time went down to 0.03 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an index on the `email` column. Otherwise, the query has to scan the entire table to count the number of rows for each email. There's no way to make it faster other than with an index.

Comment: I added the `email` column as index but there was no noticeable difference in query time, still more than 11 seconds.

Comment: Can you post the EXPLAIN output?

Comment: I just added that in the question text.

Comment: I don't understand why it's not using the index you added. I tried it on one of my large tables (7.2M rows) and it took 1.5 seconds. Post `show create table table_of_downloads`.

Comment: Is there any specific part that you want me to put in here? It's a kind of long and I rather not to publish all names and details of the table (I don't know why, sort of phobia).

Comment: I just want to see the `KEY` lines that say that there's an index on `email`.

Comment: Here it is:      PRIMARY KEY (`Request_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Uniqueness` (`RequestDate`,`RqstdFileID`,`email`(50)),
 KEY `Requested` (`Requested`(50),`RequestType`,`UserName`),
 KEY `email` (`email`(128))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1656559 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: I don't know how to put that line in a formatted way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only format in questions, not comments. Is 128 the whole size of the `email` column? You need a key that covers the entire column.

Comment: Yes, the maximum length of the `email` in the table is 125 and therefor I put 128 in the index, besides the type for `email` is `tinytext`.

Comment: Try creating the index without specifying a size -- I suspect it's not being used because it doesn't match the size of the column.

Comment: As you may know, when the type is `tinytext` you need to specify a length, and that's why I assigned 128 which is bigger than the largest value.

Comment: It looks like an index on a text type can't be used for grouping.

Comment: WOW! Impressive. I just changed the type from `tinytext` to `varchar(128)` and the query time went down to 0.03 seconds :)